# Sufficient statistic for variance in a normal distribution with mean know

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

> Let $Y_{1},Y_{n},\ldots,Y_{n}\sim N(\mu,\sigma^{2})$ with mean know. Prove that $ \displaystyle T(Y)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{1\leq i \leq n}Y_{i}^{2}$ is sufficient to $\sigma^{2}$.

**My approach:** I know that the Neyman-factorization theorem is useful here, then

\begin{eqnarray*}
  f(y_{1},y_{2},\ldots,y_{n};\sigma^{2})=\left( \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}\right)^{n}\exp \left\{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^{2}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}^{2} \right\}\cdot \mathbf{1}
    \end{eqnarray*}
but I should conclude that $\displaystyle T_{\sigma^{2}}(Y)=\sum_{1\leq i \leq n} Y_{i}^{2}$ is sufficient statistic, but is not what is requered to prove. How can I continue from here?

For the following question my post is not same of the suggested by a member of MSE. However thanks.

EDIT: If $\sum_{n}Y^{2}$ is sufficient statistic, so $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{n}Y^{2}$ is a sufficient statistic? If it's true, how can I prove this? I think that if it's true so, my approach is correct and I can conclude.

Thank you so much @tommik for your explication.

Comment: Do you mean the Fisher-Neyman factorization theorem?

Comment: @wnoise Yes, by the Fisher-Neyman criterio, but I cannot write the statistic as $\frac{1}{n}\sum Y_{n}^{2}$. Maybe is it necessary other approach?

Comment: It's just that you wrote it as "Feymann".

Comment: @wnoise Thank you, that was a typo. I corrected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find a sufficient statistic for $σ^2$ with $μ$ known, where $X_i$ is a random sample from $N(μ,σ^2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1662226/find-a-sufficient-statistic-for-%cf%832-with-%ce%bc-known-where-x-i-is-a-random-sa)

Comment: @StubbornAtom It's a similar question but your suggestion doesn't answer my question. I know that $\sum Y_{i}^{2}$ is a sufficient statistic for $\sigma^{2}$ but I'm question about $ \bar{Y_{n}}^{2}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{n}Y^{2}$. However, thank you so much.

Comment: a monotonic function of a sufficient statistic is itself sufficient (it's a very basic property)

Comment: @tommik I didn't know that property, sorry :-( In that case, it's trivial that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{n}Y_{2}$ be a sufficient statistic, because is function of a sufficient statistic $\sum_{n}Y^{2}$ is it correct?

Comment: @tommik how can I prove that statement? maybe any source that I can read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but there is an evident problem in  your statement.

$$Y_i\sim N(\mu;\sigma^2)$$

with $\mu$ known parameter; $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$

Thus

$$f(\mathbf{y},\mu,\sigma^2)=(2\pi\sigma^2)^{-n/2}\exp\Bigg\{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\Sigma_i(y_i-\mu)^2\Bigg\}=$$

$$=(2\pi\sigma^2)^{-n/2}\exp\Bigg\{-\frac{\Sigma_i y_i^2}{2\sigma^2}+\frac{\mu\Sigma_i y_i}{\sigma^2}-\frac{n\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}\Bigg\}$$

Now using the Factorization theorem you get

$$f(\mathbf{y},\mu,\sigma^2)=1\times\underbrace{(2\pi\sigma^2)^{-n/2}\exp\Bigg\{-\frac{\Sigma_i y_i^2}{2\sigma^2}+\frac{\mu\Sigma_i y_i}{\sigma^2}-\frac{n\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}\Bigg\}}_{g[t(\mathbf{y}),\sigma^2]}$$

Thus

$T=\Sigma_i Y_i^2$ IS NOT SUFFICIENT FOR $\sigma^2$ with $\mu$ knonw UNLESS $\mu=0$

Applying the same theorem, what is valid for $T$ is also valid for $T/n$

(the proof is trivial, just substitute the new estimator in the factorized expression)

Comment: Thanks, the original problem is the one that I post, however I also assumed that I correct it is $\mu = 0$. With your final clarification, I was able to conclude the problem. Thanks a lot @tommik.